# Unable to Pass Bearer Token in RTK Query Using Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I need to create a separate **PUT** request API on my React app using `axios` so I can access options that are not available using the regular `fetch` API that Redux-Toolkit Query (RTKQ) uses (i.e. upload progress). I'm able to call the API but I keep getting a 401 status because the auth token that is passed to the store file is not being sent along with the request even though I have the `prepareHeaders` method setup in the API endpoint as shown here:

```js
import { createApi } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import axios from "axios";

import TIDEAPI from "./api.json";

const BASE_URL = TIDEAPI.BASEURL;

const axiosBaseQuery =
  ({ baseUrl } = { baseUrl: "" }) =>
  async ({ url, method, data, params }) => {
    try {
      const result = await axios({ url: baseUrl + url, method, data, params });
      return { data: result.data, params: result.params };
    } catch (axiosError) {
      const err = axiosError;
      return {
        error: {
          status: err.response?.status,
          data: err.response?.data || err.message,
        },
      };
    }
  };

export const bulkApplyApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "bulkApplyApi",
  baseQuery: axiosBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: BASE_URL,
    prepareHeaders: (headers, store) => {
      const { token } = store.getState().authentication;

      if (token) {
        headers.set("authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
      }

      return headers;
    },
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    upload: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ id, data }) => ({
        url: `/API/path?id=${id}`,
        method: "put",
        data,
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

export default bulkApplyApi;

export const { useUploadMutation } = bulkApplyApi;
```

I also have endpoints that are using the regular fetch API with RTKQ where the token is being passed just fine with the `prepareHeaders` method so I suspect I need to add something else to the code above - most likely the `axiosBaseQuery` method that I pulled from the RTKQ docs but not sure what I can put there since I don't seem to be able to pass the token to this file using store. Here's the store code that I have setup that's getting the token through a slice:

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {
  reducer as searchReducer,
  searchSlice,
} from "components/search/reducer";
import { api } from "services";
import { bulkApplyApi } from "services/bulkApplyApi";
import authenticationReducer from "./authentication/authSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [api.reducerPath]: api.reducer, // normal fetch endpoints
    [bulkApplyApi.reducerPath]: bulkApplyApi.reducer, // axios endpoint
    [searchSlice.name]: searchReducer,
    authentication: authenticationReducer, // token
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(api.middleware),
});
```

Also here's the code that's calling the API endpoint:

```js
// normal fetch endpoints hooks
import {
  useLazyGetGlobalRecordIdentifierExistQuery,
  useCreateBulkUpdateMutation,
  useApplyBulkUpdateMutation,
} from "services/api";
// axios endpoint hook
import { useUploadMutation } from "services/bulkApplyApi";

export const BulkEditForm = ({data}) => {
  const [bulkUpdate, res] = useUploadMutation();

  console.log(res); 
  {/* able to console res but getting the following: 
  endpointName: "upload"
  error: {status: 401, data: 'Request failed with status code 401'}
  isError: true
  isLoading: false
  isSuccess: false
  isUninitialized: false
  originalArgs: {id: 246, data: Array(18)}
  requestId: "bsvDMeQQH-FMWeqQxfSF8"
  reset: ƒ ()
  startedTimeStamp: 1693091852046
  status: "rejected"
  */}

  const handleBulkUpdate = async () => {
    const response = await bulkUpdate({
      id,
      data,
    });
    console.log(response); // able console log but since not getting data I'm getting error obj
  };
```

If anyone has any thoughts on how I can pass the token to this API endpoint using axios I would greatly appreciate it.

I expected the token to be passed using the `prepareHeaders` method in the `axios`-based API endpoint like it's doing for the regular API endpoints using `fetch`. I couldn't find any information about passing bearer tokens using `axios` in the RTKQ docs.

Answer (score 1):

Just because the Redux-Toolkit Query `fetchBaseQuery` function consumes an options object that has a `prepareHeaders` property doesn't mean your `axiosBaseQuery` does. In fact, your `axiosBaseQuery` takes an options object that has only the `baseUrl` property, and doesn't do anything to modify the headers of outgoing requests. That's ok though, the second argument passed to the base query function is the baseQueryApi, e.g. the object that has a `getState` function to access the Redux store. You can access the state and compute and attach the headers here.

```js
const axiosBaseQuery = ({ baseURL } = { baseURL: "" }) =>
  async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
    const { getState } = api;
    const { token } = store.getState().authentication;

    try {
      const result = await axios({
        baseURL,
        headers: {
          ...args.headers,
          ...token ? { authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } : {}
        }
        ...args, // url, method, params, etc...
      });
      return result;
    } catch (err) {
      return {
        error: {
          status: err.response?.status,
          data: err.response?.data || err.message,
        },
      };
    }
  };
```

```js
export const bulkApplyApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "bulkApplyApi",
  baseQuery: axiosBaseQuery({ baseURL: BASE_URL }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    upload: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ id, data }) => ({
        url: "/API/path",
        method: "PUT",
        data,
        params: { id },
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

export default bulkApplyApi;

export const { useUploadMutation } = bulkApplyApi;
```